# iOS 9 features don't work in iPad mini

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an old iPad mini and updated it to iOS 9. However, the features don't work, such as Siri suggestions and drawing in notes app. Could somebody explain a remedy or what is up with Apple? Thanks.

I will NOT system reset as I have done so already. Maybe 9.1 beta will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple maintained support for all iOS 8 devices in iOS 9 but that meant that some devices couldn't fully support some of the new features. If it's the first generation iPad mini you have, drawing in Notes is not supported. Support starts with the iPad mini 2.

I haven't seen anything about Siri Suggestions not being supported. You could verify that your device is supported and Siri Suggestions are turned on under Settings > General > Spotlight Search. There should be a toggle for Siri Suggestions if supported.

Comment: @codeSwift4Life I know that Siri Suggestions aren't supported on the iPhone 4S.

Comment: Apple is so mean. I don't get it.

Comment: It's the nature of technology in general. Older hardware can't always support new features.

Answer (score 1):

The new Notes feature is not available on mini 1s. From the iPad User Guide.

“Note: The sketching feature is available with upgraded notes on iPad (4th generation), iPad Air (all models), and iPad mini 2 and later.”

Comment: Wow. Apple is very stupid. An iPad is an iPad no matter how old. =(

Comment: The original iPad Mini has significantly different hardware to the newer models -- for a start, it only has a 32-bit processor, while all the later models have a 64-bit processor. Sketching requires fast hardware to avoid irritating input lag, and the 32-bit Mini's likely just isn't fast enough.